# Where lies true happiness? - is this correct?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

The context is

> ... money does not really hold the key to a happy life. So where lies
> true happiness?

Do I need an auxiliary verb here, or is there a rule that would explain the non-usage of auxiliary?

Answer (score 2):

In older forms of English, *do*-support (the insertion of auxiliary *do*) was not obligatory. Over the centuries, it has become more and more frequent, and in many contexts it is now obligatory. In your sentence, I would say it is not *quite* obligatory, but almost. 99% of the time, you would hear

- So where does true happiness lie?

However, the version

- So where lies true happiness?

is still just about acceptable, although it definitely sounds poetic, flowery, and stylistically marked.